# .NET Core slow on LINUX and fast on MAC/WINDOWS

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I created a simple asp.net core webapi application using .net core 2.0 preview 2. 
It is almost the generated sample project generated by the dotnet wepapi command. All this simple applications does is to return a list of 1.000.000 instances. Those 1 million instances are fix and only generated once.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace print.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PrintController : Controller
    {
        private PrintOutList list = null;

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new PrintOutList();
                list.Build(1000000);
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(list);
        }            
    }

    public enum Weekday
    {
        Monday = 1,
        Tuesday = 2,
        Wednesday = 3
    }

    public class PrintOut
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int ActorObjectTypeId { get;set;}
        public string ActorId { get; set;}
        public int PrintObjectTypeId { get ; set ;}
        public string PrintObjectId { get; set;}
        public string Text { get; set;}
        public Weekday Weekday { get; set; }
    }

    public class PrintOutList : List<PrintOut>
    {
        public void Build(int  count)
        {
            for(int index=0;index<count;index++)
            {
                PrintOut element = new PrintOut();

                if (index == 0) element.Id = "4711";
                else element.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                element.ActorObjectTypeId = 100;
                element.ActorId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                element.PrintObjectTypeId = 200;
                element.PrintObjectId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                element.Text = "This is just a sample. " + index.ToString();
                element.Weekday = Weekday.Monday;
                Add(element);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Windows 7: 3,8 seconds (Native Machine) - GOOD**: 
Results on Windows 7 using "2.0.0-preview2-006497"
This machine is using 8 GB RAM, 8 Cores, NOT Virtualized
Staring the server: dotnet bin/release/netcoreapp2.0/publish/print.dll

```
$ curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -s http://10.40.10.23:5000/api/print -o /dev/null
          remote_ip:  10.40.10.23
           local_ip:  10.40.10.23
        num_connect:  1
      num_redirects:  0
    time_namelookup:  0,000000 Seconds
       time_connect:  0,000000 Seconds
    time_appconnect:  0,000000 Seconds
   time_pretransfer:  0,000000 Seconds
      time_redirect:  0,000000 Seconds
 time_starttransfer:  1,232000 Seconds
      size_download:  294888859 Bytes
        size_header:  148 Bytes
       size_request:  89 Bytes
     speed_download:  77479994,000 Bytes/s
----------------------------------------------
         time_total:  3,806000
```

**RHEL 7.2: 24,78 seconds (Virtual Machine VMWare Workstation) - BAD**: 
Results on RHEL 7.2 using "2.0.0-preview2-006497"
This machine is runing within VMWARE Workstation using 2 GB RAM, 2 Cores
Staring the server: [root@node0 print]# /opt/dotnet/dotnet ./bin/release/netcoreapp2.0/publish/print.dll

```
[root@node0 ~]# curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -s http://10.40.10.59:5000/api/print -o /dev/null
          *remote_ip:  10.40.10.59
           local_ip:  10.40.10.59
        num_connect:  1
      num_redirects:  0
    time_namelookup:  0.000 Seconds
       time_connect:  0.001 Seconds
    time_appconnect:  0.000 Seconds
   time_pretransfer:  0.001 Seconds
      time_redirect:  0.000 Seconds
 time_starttransfer:  21.286 Seconds
      size_download:  294888859 Bytes
        size_header:  148 Bytes
       size_request:  89 Bytes
     speed_download:  11937938.000 Bytes/s
----------------------------------------------
         time_total:  24.702*
```

**RHEL 7.4: 21,6 seconds (Virtual Machine ESX Server) - BAD**: 
Results on RHEL 7.4 using "2.0.0-preview2-006497"
This machine is runing within VMWARE Workstation using 4 GB RAM, 2 Cores
Staring the server: [root@node0 print]# /opt/dotnet/dotnet ./bin/release/netcoreapp2.0/publish/print.dll

```
[root@node1 ~]# curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -s http://10.40.40.40:5000/api/print -o /dev/null
          remote_ip:  10.40.40.40
           local_ip:  10.40.40.40
        num_connect:  1
      num_redirects:  0
    time_namelookup:  0.000 Seconds
       time_connect:  0.000 Seconds
    time_appconnect:  0.000 Seconds
   time_pretransfer:  0.000 Seconds
      time_redirect:  0.000 Seconds
 time_starttransfer:  18.043 Seconds
      size_download:  294888859 Bytes
        size_header:  148 Bytes
       size_request:  89 Bytes
     speed_download:  13641913.000 Bytes/s
----------------------------------------------
         time_total:  21.616
```

**OSX: 4,0 seconds (Native Machine) - GOOD** : 
Results on OSX (current cersion)
This machine is using 16 GB RAM, 4 Cores
I just have a screenshot of the results.
The total time was round about 4 seconds

On a **Fedora 25** linux I also had the bad results of 25 seconds.

My question is about the performance difference using .net core on windows and linux. Is .net core on linux generally slower than on windows? If not, what is a possible explanation for such a big difference?

Comment: You should report to the relevant .NET Core repos at GitHub. Generally speaking, .NET Core development is more focused on API surface till 2.0, and more performance tuning would come in the future. There is currently no guarantee that its performance is the same on every platforms (I don't think Java guarantee that either).

Comment: @Dieter, are you comparing the speed of .NET core in native vs virtual machines? Did you try running .NET core on a native Linux machine instead of a virtual one? Comparing apples and oranges is not always the best approach. Did you really expect that a virtual machine will behave as fast as a native bare bone OS?

Comment: @Lex Li: Just created the issue on github. I don't expect the same performance on different plattforms.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: No. I do not expect the same performance, but todays world is virtual. Even in our company and mostly all of our customers are using any kind of virtualization. But you are right, i am still missing the same test on an virtual windows system. But I only expect a plus on time of a few seconds (1 to 5 seconds).

Comment: If todays world is virtual then make sure that you are running a virtual Windows and MAC in order to be able to compare with a virtual Linux. Otherwise you are just wasting your time. A native bare bone OS will always be faster than a virtual one no matter how hard you try. This basically makes your question meaningless and I am voting for it to be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you cannot compare the speed of a native bare bone operating system with a virtual one.

Comment: By the way, don't hesitate to come back here with actual comparable figures once you have them. I am sure it will be interesting to see how well .NET core behaves on the various platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I made one more test using Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, 4 GB RAM, 2 Cores, hosted within VMWare Workstation 12 Pro. Within this test I was using the official release 2.0.0. Still GOOD.

```
$ curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -s http://192.168.178.117:5000/api/print -o /dev/null
          remote_ip:  192.168.178.117
           local_ip:  192.168.178.120
        num_connect:  1
      num_redirects:  0
    time_namelookup:  0,000000 Seconds
       time_connect:  0,000000 Seconds
    time_appconnect:  0,000000 Seconds
   time_pretransfer:  0,000000 Seconds
      time_redirect:  0,000000 Seconds
 time_starttransfer:  1,716000 Seconds
      size_download:  294888859 Bytes
        size_header:  148 Bytes
       size_request:  93 Bytes
     speed_download:  60789292,000 Bytes/s
----------------------------------------------
         time_total:  4,851000
```

This is a value I expected. I suspect there are some internal "things" within the JSON serialization in Linux. My test class has 7 properties. All togehter there are 7 millions "json strings" to create. BUT, maybe i am wrong and it's just a setting to activate on a linux machine.

Hopefully it's only this kind of tricky setting or a simple bug which can be fixed within a future release. For me, the availability of a cross plattform c# is a kind of dream, 10 years old :)

Comment: On Windows Server 2016 Core (2 GB RAM, 4 Cores) running within VMware Workstation I get 4.88 seconds.

Comment: Following comments can be done on github. [link](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/825) It seems to be a problem with the function Guid.NewGuid on linux.